# Writing cat in OCaml: use of Unix.read

Tags: unix, ocaml, cat

I'm trying to write small utilities to get used to Unix programming with OCaml. Here's my try for `cat`:

```
    open Unix ;;

    let buffer_size = 10
    let buffer = String.create buffer_size

    let rec cat = function
      | [] -> ()
      | x :: xs ->
        let descr = openfile x [O_RDONLY] 0 in

        let rec loop () =
          match read descr buffer 0 buffer_size with
            | 0 -> ()
            | _ -> print_string buffer; loop () in
        loop ();
        print_newline ();
        close descr;
        cat xs ;;


    handle_unix_error cat (List.tl (Array.to_list Sys.argv))
```

It seems that the problem is that, on the last call to `read`, the buffer doesn't entirely fill since there's nothing more to read, the end of what the buffer previously contained gets printed too. I read a few example codes using `read` and they didn't seem to use `String.create` every time they refill the buffer (which, anyway, still fills it with some characters...) ; so what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return of `Unix.read` (which you ignore, except checking for 0) is the number of characters that you've read, so you only should use that many characters of the buffer.

But really, why bother using the low-level Unix stuff? Why not use the regular OCaml file opening and reading functions?

Comment: I'm reading "Unix system programming with Objective Caml", which is talking about this Unix module. Should I actually avoid it?

Comment: @rochem It depends on your objectives. That course will give you Unix knowledge that you can transfer to other languages (passing a buffer and a buffer size and getting the number of chars read in return is the typical way in C). Because these calls match the C calls so closely, they are almost never used in usual Caml programming, so what this course won't teach you is how to write idiomatic OCaml programs.